# Rails: How to avoid a repetition of including the same module in several models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I have several models that all include the same module:

```
class MyModel1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModuleName
end

class MyModel2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModuleName
end

class MyModel3 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModuleName
end
```

Instead of including the module in each model, I tried to the following:

```
class MyNewModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModuleName
end

class MyModel1 < MyNewModel
end

class MyModel2 < MyNewModel
end

class MyModel3 < MyNewModel
end
```

but this ends up with an error saying that `my_new_models` table does not exist.

What is the proper way to avoid the repetition of `include MyModuleName` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the model inheritance technique to work, you need to set `self.abstract_class = true` in `MyNewModel`:

```
class MyNewModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  include MyModuleName
end

class MyModel1 < MyNewModel
end

class MyModel2 < MyNewModel
end

class MyModel3 < MyNewModel
end
```

Comment: Thanks! What does `self.abstract_class = true` exactly do ?

Comment: It's difficult to sum up in a comment and you're probably best off Googling the question. Generally speaking, an abstract class is used to contain abstract methods which will be used by it's subclasses (like what you're doing). Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. To look at what Rails does with it, you'll have to dig into the AR source.

Comment: Generally, I know what abstract class is. But, even if the class is not abstract, I still can define methods in it and use them in the subclasses. So why in this case the class must be abstract ? And why Rails tried to find the `my_new_models` table ? Setting the class to be abstract like you suggested solved the issue. I just want to understand why!

Comment: this is a good tip! ; @Mischa: `ActiveRecord` deduces the table-name from the model-name (thus class-name), by pluralizing it. That's why it went looking for the `my_new_models` table.